# How to get actual file path for pdf file in android?

Tags: android

I successfully got the actual address of Video file using this code.

```
Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
assert cursor != null;
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
mediaPath1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

Since Pdf is not media file i can't use MediaStore.

Using the below mentioned code gave me "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/....." as the path

Actually i am uploading pdf files using retrofit 2 to server.
When i hardcoded the address as shown in file manager to the mediapath1 i was able to upload the file successfully.

I found many solution for getting address from uri but none gave me the correct address.

Thanks in advance.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
File file = new File(uri.toString());
mediaPath1 = file.getAbsolutePath();
uploadPdf();
```

Comment: I found the actual problem while uploading the pdf file to server, so i updated the question. I am not able to get the real file address of the pdf files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending hours i finally got the answer.

http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-when-select.html

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class ImageFilePath 
{


 /**
  * Method for return file path of Gallery image 
  * 
  * @param context
  * @param uri
  * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
  */
 public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) 
 {

  //check here to KITKAT or new version
  final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
  Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

  // DocumentProvider
  if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

   // ExternalStorageProvider
   if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
   final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
   final String[] split = docId.split(":");
   final String type = split[0];

   if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
   }
  }
  // DownloadsProvider
  else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

   final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
   Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

   return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
  }
  // MediaProvider
  else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
    final String type = split[0];

    Uri contentUri = null;
    if ("image".equals(type)) {
       contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
       contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
       contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

   final String selection = "_id=?";
   final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
   split[1]
 };

  return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
 }
}
 // MediaStore (and general)
 else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

     // Return the remote address
     if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
     return uri.getLastPathSegment();

    return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
  }
  // File
  else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
   return uri.getPath();
   }

   return null;
 }

 /**
  * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
  * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
  *
  * @param context The context.
  * @param uri The Uri to query.
  * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
  * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
  * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
  */
 public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
   String[] selectionArgs) {

  Cursor cursor = null;
  final String column = "_data";
  final String[] projection = {
   column
  };

  try {
   cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
 null);
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
   return cursor.getString(index);
   }
  } finally {
   if (cursor != null)
    cursor.close();
  }
  return null;
 }

 /**
  * @param uri The Uri to check.
  * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
  */
 public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }

 /**
  * @param uri The Uri to check.
  * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
  */
 public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
  return 
"com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }

 /**
  * @param uri The Uri to check.
  * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
  */
 public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }

 /**
  * @param uri The Uri to check.
  * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
  */
 public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
  return 
"com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }
}
```

Comment: I am type as `document` in `isMediaDocument` . What to do in that case?

Comment: Crashes on Samsung

Comment: not working in pdf file uri

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved after copying that pdf file to cache directory Please check the complete solution here:

```
public static final String DOCUMENTS_DIR = "documents";

if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        if (id != null && id.startsWith("raw:")) {
            return id.substring(4);
        }

        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
        };

        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
            try {
                String path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                if (path != null) {
                    return path;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        // path could not be retrieved using ContentResolver, therefore copy file to accessible cache using streams
        String fileName = getFileName(context, uri);
        File cacheDir = getDocumentCacheDir(context);
        File file = generateFileName(fileName, cacheDir);
        String destinationPath = null;
        if (file != null) {
            destinationPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            saveFileFromUri(context, uri, destinationPath);
        }

        return destinationPath;
    }

public static String getFileName(@NonNull Context context, Uri uri) {
String mimeType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
String filename = null;

if (mimeType == null && context != null) {
    String path = getPath(context, uri);
    if (path == null) {
        filename = getName(uri.toString());
    } else {
        File file = new File(path);
        filename = file.getName();
    }
} else {
    Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (returnCursor != null) {
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
        returnCursor.close();
    }
}

return filename;
}

public static String getName(String filename) {
if (filename == null) {
    return null;
}
int index = filename.lastIndexOf('/');
return filename.substring(index + 1);
}

public static File getDocumentCacheDir(@NonNull Context context) {
File dir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOCUMENTS_DIR);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
//        logDir(context.getCacheDir());
//        logDir(dir);

return dir;
}

@Nullable
public static File generateFileName(@Nullable String name, File directory) {
if (name == null) {
    return null;
}

File file = new File(directory, name);

if (file.exists()) {
    String fileName = name;
    String extension = "";
    int dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex > 0) {
        fileName = name.substring(0, dotIndex);
        extension = name.substring(dotIndex);
    }

    int index = 0;

    while (file.exists()) {
        index++;
        name = fileName + '(' + index + ')' + extension;
        file = new File(directory, name);
    }
}

try {
    if (!file.createNewFile()) {
        return null;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Log.w(TAG, e);
    return null;
}

//logDir(directory);

return file;
}

private static void saveFileFromUri(Context context, Uri uri, String destinationPath) 
{
InputStream is = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
try {
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationPath, false));
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    is.read(buf);
    do {
        bos.write(buf);
    } while (is.read(buf) != -1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (is != null) is.close();
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Appreciated the help on this [thread](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/issues/101#issuecomment-438949085)

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed it with a very easy way

You only need to remove `file:/` from URI and you will have the path to file.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1002){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String[] pathArr = myFile.getAbsolutePath().split(":/");
            String path = pathArr[pathArr.length - 1];
        } 
    }
}
```